# extract path name based on a string

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, logic

Below is my worked examples:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

test2 = ['register/adam/users_photo3.jpg', 'register/adam/users_photo4.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/adam/users_photo3.jpg', 'register/adam/users_photo4.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg']

test = ["justin","adam"]


filter_list = []
for p,q in zip_longest(test,list_of_files):
    for r in list_of_files:
        if str(p) in r:
            filter_list.append(r)       


testmain=[p for p,r in zip_longest(test2,filter_list) if str(r) not in str(p)]
print(testmain)
```

I want the opposite output url of test. example "steve" url needed as output !
Needed output: All steve urls needed in output.

Hope I clarified myself and I get some response, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are zipping the names. You can use `not` [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to test for no matches:

```
test2 = ['register/adam/users_photo3.jpg', 'register/adam/users_photo4.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/adam/users_photo3.jpg', 'register/adam/users_photo4.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg', 
'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg']

test = ["justin","adam"]

[url for url in test2 if not any(name in url for name in test)]
```

This will give you:

```
'[register/steve/users_photo1.jpg',
 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg',
 'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg',
 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg']
```

If `test` is long, these are probably some optimizations, but this should work for normal sized inputs.

Comment: This is working as expected and let me test some testcases and will tick verify.

Comment: Yes its working ! I didnt know a simple "any" would work on this. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list comprehension along with `re.search`:

```py
test2 = ['register/adam/users_photo3.jpg', 
    'register/adam/users_photo4.jpg', 
    'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 
    'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
    'register/adam/users_photo3.jpg', 
    'register/adam/users_photo4.jpg', 
    'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 
    'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
    'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 
    'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg', 
    'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg', 
    'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg', 
    'register/justin/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/justin/users_photo2.jpg']

test = ["justin", "adam"]
regex = r'/(?:' + '|'.join(test) + r')/'
output = [x for x in test2 if not re.search(regex, x)]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg',
 'register/steve/users_photo1.jpg', 'register/steve/users_photo2.jpg']
```